# Get only top part of camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I am stuck at this Issue since couple of days. What I want is only part of the camera to be shown on screen. This is what I want:[image]

This is what I have done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBeautyContent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <SurfaceView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBeautyCamera"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scanText"
            android:text="Scanning..."
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>



@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
        final LinearLayout inflate = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.main, null);

        final SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewBeautyCamera);
        final SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceView.getHolder();

        WindowManager mW = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int screenWidth = mW.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        int screenHeight = mW.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams slayout = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
        slayout.width = screenWidth;
        slayout.height = screenHeight;
        surfaceView.requestLayout();

        final ScrollView beautyContent = (ScrollView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    camera = getCamera();
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    camera.startPreview();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Lucy", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }
        });

        addContentView(inflate, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
public Camera getCamera() {
    try {
        final Camera open = Camera.open();
        return open;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("Lucy", ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

When i do this I get:
[image]

The Idea is to set the size of SurfaceView as full screen but reduce the size of scroll view. But what I want is the first Image. What am I doing wrong?

Observations:

When I scroll the view up completely. Go back to Home Screen and open the app again. i get the first image. But if I scroll again and go back to main to come back, i get the second Image.

Any other strategy?

PS:
 1. Having other view on top of camera is also option, but I cannot use it for lengthy reasons

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) why can't you use `setContentView`? 2) why do you want the `SurfaceView` in fullscreen but the `ScrollView` with a reduced height? Do you want to display just a portion of the image, but be able to scroll it?

Comment: 1) I cannot use `setContentView` because I am building a plugin for phonegap. And my view will go on top of browser basically. Hence.
2) Yup. Basically I am trying to put the camera feed in a scrollview and restrict the height of scroller to 200. This way I will only be able to see just a part of the feed.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion added that method

Comment: I think you should create a view and make it invisible or change its opactity to 0. and it will take space  and also transparent. And the area you don't want to show camera but that view over there..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the height settings for your elements:
Your root element should be a relative layout, you can then set the fixed height of the camera view and set the textview with the text to height match parent and layout_below the scroll view.

Comment: I tried doing it. Didn't work. Can you provide a more concrete version of your saying.

Comment: Could you post the code that you tried please, so I can check it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you put `surfaceView` in the `scrollView` But I put up with your layout file and its works for me as you show in expected snapshot result .

**Edits:**

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBeautyContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <SurfaceView
                    android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBeautyCamera"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp" />
                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/scanText"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:text="Scanning..." >
                 </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
      </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I just realized that this is not a complete answer. There is one Issue with it. The text view actually comes at the bottom where as it should just below the scroll. Doing `android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"` does not help.

Comment: AS you shown in image ,its hard to understand that you wanted that textview not below the camera view but in the scrollview . Anyways , you can still put that textview in child layout of scroll view with fix dimension . Please see edits

Comment: Nope. This new edit does not work at all. Now the camera occupies full screen. 
What I meant by text view under scroll is that, it should just come below the camera and not at bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

try this layout.But don't understand why use scrollView.

I post 2 layout

**First one where surface mean camera face is 160dp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBeautyContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBeautyCamera"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scanText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayoutBeautyContent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="Scanning..." >
    </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**2nd one is, camera will capture fullscreen size picture but u can see only 160 window at time of capture**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBeautyContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceViewBeautyCamera"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scanText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Scanning..." >
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The Issue with the answer is that, the `TextView` will occupy the rest of the screen. Where as what I want is that the TextView is `wrap_content` and the remaining bottom part of the screen is empty (basically the view lying a layer below is shown. This is also the reason why I am using `addContentView`)